# how to use count in order by in laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to use count in order by and I have used following 2 ways

First

```
DB::table('user_skill')
        ->join('skill_category', 'user_skill.skill_category_id', '=', 'skill_category.skill_category_id')            
        ->select(DB::raw('user_skill.skill_category_id', 'skill_category.skill_name','count(user_skill.skill_category_id) as totalIds'))
        ->orderBy('totalIds','desc')
        ->groupBy('user_skill.skill_category_id')
        ->get();
```

Second

```
DB::table('user_skill')
        ->join('skill_category', 'user_skill.skill_category_id', '=', 'skill_category.skill_category_id')            
        ->select(DB::raw('user_skill.skill_category_id', 'skill_category.skill_name'))
        ->orderBy('count(user_skill.skill_category_id)','desc')
        ->groupBy('user_skill.skill_category_id')
        ->get();
```

But both are giving following error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'totalIds' in 'order clause'
```

any suggestion, how I can solve this?

Comment: try adding the table name before the column name on the order by function like `user_skill.totalIds`. I'm not sure but maybe we get lucky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the raw function, you will see that it only accepts one argument.

```
public static function raw($value){        
    return \Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::raw($value);
}
```

Furthermore, what you do is passing more than one argument so that nothing is passed but the first argument.

You can fix it like below,

```
->select(DB::raw('user_skill.skill_category_id, skill_category.skill_name, count(user_skill.skill_category_id) as totalIds'))
```

Or

```
->select('user_skill.skill_category_id', 'skill_category.skill_name', DB::raw('count(user_skill.skill_category_id) as totalIds'))
```